# branch.io custom event in react native is not triggering reward rule

Tags: react-native, branch.io

I have a react native project that is dedicated towards building iOS application. I set identity `branch.setIdentity('yashKalwani');` this way then i create a branch universal object as shown in documentation.

```
let branchUniversalObject = await branch.createBranchUniversalObject('canonicalIdentifier', {
  title: 'Cool Content!',
  contentDescription: 'Cool Content Description',
  contentMetadata: {
    customMetadata: {
      customMetadata1: 'abcd',
      customMetadata2: 'efgh'
    }
  }
});
```

I now trigger a custom event `new BranchEvent('threepoints', branchUniversalObject).logEvent()` but this custom event does not trigger the rule that I have inside my rewards in branch.io dashboard.

Rule: all acting users get **3** default credits every time they trigger the event `threepoints`.

Am i missing out on something? Why is the rule not triggering even though the event is being logged in my Dashboard. I am able to view that the custom event has been fired via my liveview event tracking feature.

Answer (score 0):

Currently for the referrals feature, v2 events are not supported:

- https://docs.branch.io/pages/viral/referrals/#guide

This means that you cannot use `logEvent`. You must use `userCompletedAction` instead e.g. `branch.userCompletedAction('threepoints')`:

- [Example](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/react-native-branch-deep-linking/blob/a1f4cc1825b08508bda64bde30dd090c130f02db/examples/testbed_native_ios/src/BranchMethods.js#L107)

Comment: Hey i tried executing it this way but it still doesn't trigger the points.
Also do i have to create a new BranchUniversalObject every time i call userCompletedAction or is it alright if i call it once and then re-use it again.

Comment: Do i also have to download my app from a branch link to be able to allocate rewards to users?

Comment: You can re-use the same BUO. Also, you must complete the entire referral flow so that means a user must click a Branch link, install the app for the first time (required unless debug mode is enabled), then trigger the event.

Comment: I have turned the debug mode to true. (But I still get +clicked_from_branch: false when I getLatestParams) And I am using userActionCompleted. Any idea why the custom event is triggering but the referral rewards are not being allotted to the user?
Also can you explain what the subscribe callback does? Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is the correct answer. V2 events are not supported with the referral feature.